# Inserting last known price on a 5 minute interval using PostgreSql

Tags: postgresql, finance

I have this table for storing tick by tick argentinian bonds data:

```
bonos=# \d preciosrt
                                          Table "public.preciosrt"
   Column   |          Type          | Collation | Nullable |                    Default                    
------------+------------------------+-----------+----------+-----------------------------------------------
 idpreciort | integer                |           | not null | nextval('preciosrt_idpreciort_seq'::regclass)
 fecha      | date                   |           | not null | now()::date
 ticker     | text                   |           | not null | 
 bid        | numeric                |           |          | 
 ask        | numeric                |           |          | 
 hora       | time without time zone |           | not null | 
 bidqty     | integer                |           |          | 
 askqty     | integer                |           |          | 
 last       | numeric                |           |          | 
 volume     | integer                |           |          | 
 settlement | character varying(4)   |           |          |
```

With this query I can get all the last prices of the "AL29" bond between 13:55 and 14:30:

```
select 
row_number() over(), hora, last 
from preciosrt 
where 
ticker='AL29' and 
settlement='48hs' and 
fecha=now()::date - interval '1 day' and
hora >= '13:55:00' and hora <= '14:30:00'
order by hora;
```

```
 row_number |   hora   |  last  
------------+----------+--------
          1 | 13:55:18 | 6260.0
          2 | 13:56:00 | 6264.5
          3 | 13:56:29 | 6264.5
          4 | 13:57:08 | 6265.0
          5 | 14:03:07 | 6266.0
          6 | 14:05:16 | 6266.0
          7 | 14:06:19 | 6266.0
          8 | 14:06:33 | 6270.0
          9 | 14:07:08 | 6276.5
         10 | 14:07:24 | 6299.5
         11 | 14:09:56 | 6318.5
         12 | 14:11:24 | 6300.0
         13 | 14:20:58 | 6315.0
         14 | 14:24:58 | 6315.0
         15 | 14:27:54 | 6315.0
         16 | 14:28:06 | 6319.0
(16 rows)
```

Let's pay attention to rows 12 and 13, where a tick was at `14:11:24` and the next one at `14:20:58`.

Now, with this query I can show the ticks in 5 minutes intervals (span from `14:00:00` to `15:00:00`):

```
select
ticker,
last,
intervalo
from(
select 
ticker, last, 
row_number() over (
        partition by to_timestamp(floor((extract('epoch' from hora) / 300 )) * 300) at time zone  'UTC'
        order by hora desc
) as rownum,
to_char(to_timestamp(floor((extract('epoch' from hora) / 300 )) * 300) at time zone 'UTC', 'HH24:MI:SS') as intervalo
from preciosrt p1
where 
p1.ticker='AL29' and p1.settlement='48hs' and 
p1.fecha=now()::date - interval '1 day'
) x
where x.rownum=1 and x.intervalo >= '14:00:00' and x.intervalo <= '15:00:00';
```

```
 ticker |  last  | intervalo 
--------+--------+-----------
 AL29   | 6266.0 | 14:00:00
 AL29   | 6318.5 | 14:05:00
 AL29   | 6300.0 | 14:10:00
 AL29   | 6315.0 | 14:20:00
 AL29   | 6319.0 | 14:25:00
 AL29   | 6323.0 | 14:30:00
 AL29   | 6320.0 | 14:35:00
 AL29   | 6318.0 | 14:40:00
 AL29   | 6329.5 | 14:50:00
 AL29   | 6315.0 | 14:55:00
 AL29   | 6316.0 | 15:00:00
(11 rows)
```

As you can see, at 14:10 the last price was `6300.0`, and the next one was at 14:20 `6315`.

```
 AL29   | 6300.0 | 14:10:00
 AL29   | 6315.0 | 14:20:00
```

Now I want to add the missing data at `14:15:00` containig the value of the last known tick, that is `6300`. How can I do this using a PostgreSql query?.

**Edit**

Using `generate_series` I can create the whole interval, then left join to my data, but as you can guess the gaps are still there:

```
with minutes as (                                                                                                                            
  select generate_series(                                                                                                                    
    timestamp '2000-01-01 11:00:00',                                                                                                         
    timestamp '2000-01-01 17:00:00',                                                                                                         
    '5 minute'::interval                                                                                                                     
  ) as tt                                                                                                                                    
)                                                                                                                                            
select                                                                                                                                       
to_char(minutes.tt, 'HH24:MI:SS'),                                                                                                           
x2.*                                                                                                                                         
from minutes                                                                                                                                 
left join                                                                                                                                    
(                                                                                                                                            
select                                                                                                                                       
ticker,                                                                                                                                      
last,                                                                                                                                        
intervalo                                                                                                                                    
from(                                                                                                                                        
select                                                                                                                                       
ticker, last,                                                                                                                                
row_number() over (                                                                                                                          
  partition by to_timestamp(floor((extract('epoch' from hora) / 300 )) * 300) at time zone  'UTC'                                            
  order by hora desc                                                                                                                         
) as rownum,                                                                                                                                 
to_char(to_timestamp(floor((extract('epoch' from hora) / 300 )) * 300) at time zone 'UTC', 'HH24:MI:SS') as intervalo                        
from preciosrt p1                                                                                                                            
where                                                                                                                                        
p1.ticker='AL29' and p1.settlement='48hs' and                                                                                                
p1.fecha=now()::date - interval '1 day'                                                                                                      
) x                                                                                                                                          
where x.rownum=1                                                                                                                             
) x2 on x2.intervalo = to_char(minutes.tt, 'HH24:MI:SS');
```

```
 14:05:00 | AL29   | 6318.5 | 14:05:00
 14:10:00 | AL29   | 6300.0 | 14:10:00
 14:15:00 |        |        | 
 14:20:00 | AL29   | 6315.0 | 14:20:00
 14:25:00 | AL29   | 6319.0 | 14:25:00
 14:30:00 | AL29   | 6323.0 | 14:30:00
 14:35:00 | AL29   | 6320.0 | 14:35:00
 14:40:00 | AL29   | 6318.0 | 14:40:00
 14:45:00 |        |        | 
 14:50:00 | AL29   | 6329.5 | 14:50:00
 14:55:00 | AL29   | 6315.0 | 14:55:00
 15:00:00 | AL29   | 6316.0 | 15:00:00
 15:05:00 | AL29   | 6320.5 | 15:05:00
 15:10:00 | AL29   | 6374.5 | 15:10:00
 15:15:00 | AL29   | 6344.0 | 15:15:00
 15:20:00 | AL29   | 6395.0 | 15:20:00
 15:25:00 | AL29   | 6400.0 | 15:25:00
 15:30:00 | AL29   | 6355.0 | 15:30:00
 15:35:00 | AL29   | 6400.0 | 15:35:00
 15:40:00 | AL29   | 6395.0 | 15:40:00
```

**Edit 2**

I think I found it:

```
with minutes as (                                                                                                                            
  select generate_series(                                                                                                                    
    timestamp '2000-01-01 11:00:00',                                                                                                         
    timestamp '2000-01-01 17:00:00',                                                                                                         
    '5 minute'::interval                                                                                                                     
  ) as tt                                                                                                                                    
)                                                                                                                                            
select                                                                                                                                       
to_char(minutes.tt, 'HH24:MI:SS'),                                                                                                           
coalesce(x2.last, lag(last) over()) as last                                                                                                  
from minutes                                                                                                                                 
left join                                                                                                                                    
(                                                                                                                                            
select                                                                                                                                       
ticker,                                                                                                                                      
last,                                                                                                                                        
intervalo                                                                                                                                    
from(                                                                                                                                        
select                                                                                                                                       
ticker, last,                                                                                                                                
row_number() over (                                                                                                                          
  partition by to_timestamp(floor((extract('epoch' from hora) / 300 )) * 300) at time zone  'UTC'                                            
  order by hora desc                                                                                                                         
) as rownum,                                                                                                                                 
to_char(to_timestamp(floor((extract('epoch' from hora) / 300 )) * 300) at time zone 'UTC', 'HH24:MI:SS') as intervalo                        
from preciosrt p1                                                                                                                            
where                                                                                                                                        
p1.ticker='AL29' and p1.settlement='48hs' and                                                                                                
p1.fecha=now()::date - interval '1 day'                                                                                                      
) x                                                                                                                                          
where x.rownum=1                                                                                                                             
) x2 on x2.intervalo = to_char(minutes.tt, 'HH24:MI:SS');
```

Gives this result:

```
to_char  |  last  
----------+--------
 11:00:00 |       
 11:05:00 |       
 11:10:00 |       
 11:15:00 |       
 11:20:00 |       
 11:25:00 |       
 11:30:00 |       
 11:35:00 | 6225.0
 11:40:00 | 6225.0
 11:45:00 | 6205.0
 11:50:00 | 6233.5
 11:55:00 | 6233.0
 12:00:00 | 6225.0
 12:05:00 | 6222.0
 12:10:00 | 6222.0
 12:15:00 | 6228.5
 12:20:00 | 6220.0
 12:25:00 | 6249.0
 12:30:00 | 6258.5
 12:35:00 | 6257.5
 12:40:00 | 6265.0
 12:45:00 | 6280.0
 12:50:00 | 6296.0
 12:55:00 | 6277.0
 13:00:00 | 6270.0
 13:05:00 | 6270.0
 13:10:00 | 6269.0
 13:15:00 | 6250.0
 13:20:00 | 6260.0
 13:25:00 | 6250.0
 13:30:00 | 6250.0
 13:35:00 | 6250.0
 13:40:00 | 6250.0
 13:45:00 | 6250.0
 13:50:00 | 6260.0
 13:55:00 | 6265.0
 14:00:00 | 6266.0
 14:05:00 | 6318.5
 14:10:00 | 6300.0
 14:15:00 | 6300.0
 14:20:00 | 6315.0
 14:25:00 | 6319.0
 14:30:00 | 6323.0
 14:35:00 | 6320.0
 14:40:00 | 6318.0
 14:45:00 | 6318.0
 14:50:00 | 6329.5
 14:55:00 | 6315.0
 15:00:00 | 6316.0
 15:05:00 | 6320.5
 15:10:00 | 6374.5
 15:15:00 | 6344.0
 15:20:00 | 6395.0
 15:25:00 | 6400.0
 15:30:00 | 6355.0
 15:35:00 | 6400.0
 15:40:00 | 6395.0
 15:45:00 | 6372.0
 15:50:00 | 6405.0
 15:55:00 | 6420.0
 16:00:00 | 6420.0
 16:05:00 | 6410.5
 16:10:00 | 6400.0
 16:15:00 | 6417.0
 16:20:00 | 6395.0
 16:25:00 | 6390.0
 16:30:00 | 6388.5
 16:35:00 | 6390.0
 16:40:00 | 6390.0
 16:45:00 | 6381.0
 16:50:00 | 6380.5
 16:55:00 | 6380.5
 17:00:00 | 6379.0
```

**Edit 3**

Adapted from Tomáš Záluský answer:

```
with minutes as (                                                                                                                            
  select generate_series(                                                                                                                    
    timestamp '2000-01-01 11:00:00',                                                                                                         
    timestamp '2000-01-01 17:00:00',                                                                                                         
    '5 minute'::interval                                                                                                                     
  ) as tt                                                                                                                                    
),  t as (                                                                                                                                   
  select                                                                                                                                     
  to_char(minutes.tt, 'HH24:MI:SS'),                                                                                                         
  x2.*,                                                                                                                                      
  minutes.tt                                                                                                                                 
  from minutes                                                                                                                               
  left join                                                                                                                                  
  (                                                                                                                                          
  select                                                                                                                                     
  ticker,                                                                                                                                    
  last,                                                                                                                                      
  intervalo                                                                                                                                  
  from(                                                                                                                                      
  select                                                                                                                                     
  ticker, last,                                                                                                                              
  row_number() over (                                                                                                                        
    partition by to_timestamp(floor((extract('epoch' from hora) / 300 )) * 300) at time zone  'UTC'                                          
    order by hora desc                                                                                                                       
  ) as rownum,                                                                                                                               
  to_char(to_timestamp(floor((extract('epoch' from hora) / 300 )) * 300) at time zone 'UTC', 'HH24:MI:SS') as intervalo                      
  from preciosrt p1                                                                                                                          
  where                                                                                                                                      
  p1.ticker='AL29' and p1.settlement='48hs' and                                                                                              
  p1.fecha=now()::date - interval '1 day'                                                                                                    
  ) x                                                                                                                                        
  where x.rownum=1                                                                                                                           
  ) x2 on x2.intervalo = to_char(minutes.tt, 'HH24:MI:SS')                                                                                   
), x as (                                                                                                                                    
  select t.*, count(ticker) over(order by tt) as parttn from t                                                                               
) 
select                                                                                                                                       
 tt::time,                                                                                                                                   
 first_value(ticker) over(partition by parttn order by tt),                                                                                  
 first_value(last) over(partition by parttn order by tt)                                                                                     
from x;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are solving problem of filling missing values from previous rows.

Left join is good start. You need to substitute any `null` value of `ticker` and `last` column for last nonnull value in ordering by `minutes.tt`. This could be normally achieved using `lag` window function. The `lag` function returns value from previous row. Although it would work in your concrete case, I assume there can generally be gap of many consecutive 5m intervals. In this case, `lag` could be used only with `ignore nulls` clause: `case when ticker is null then lag(ticker) ignore nulls over (order by tt) else ticker end`. Unfortunately it is currently not supported by Postgres.

Workaround: use `count` analytic function to get sequence of only nonnull values (i.e. those joined by left join) in ordering by `tt`. The function returns number which increases with each nonnull value but stays same with each `null` value. This number describes chunks consisted of first nonnull value and potentially many following `null` values. Hence you can use this number to define partition. The data you want is the `first_value` over that partition.

```
with minutes as (                                                                                                                            
  ...YOUR SERIES...
), t as (
  select                                                                                                                                       
  to_char(minutes.tt, 'HH24:MI:SS') as tt,                                                                                                           
  ...YOUR QUERY...
), x as (
  select t.*, count(ticker) over (order by tt) as parttn from t
)
select tt
     , first_value(ticker) over (partition by parttn order by tt)
     , first_value(last) over (partition by parttn order by tt)
from x
```

[Simplified fiddle here.](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=490ee891dbc4bc5d7f1b70ede52451f6) If I overlooked something important in your data then roll your own fiddle please.

Comment: Your mention to `lag` helped me to came up with the **edit2**.

Comment: Try to delete rows `14:20:58` and `14:24:58` from your sample input. Does it still return data for `14:20:00` interval?

Comment: Mmm, you are right, when the gap exceeds the interval (5 min) it is still shown.

Comment: I added the **Edit 3** adapted from your answer, I'll mark yours as the correct answer. Thank you!.